# Present/past or past/past. Sequence of tenses

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

"When they ask you about the things you thought they had no idea about"

OR

"When they ask you about the things you thought they have no idea about" ?

Present and past, both tenses here, confused what to use in clause one.

Comment: We need an independent clause to show whether this is habitual, future etc. eg 'What will you do when they ask you about the things you thought they had no idea about?"

Comment: Not future here, it would be: How you usually react when... etc.

Comment: I'd say 'had' is necessary, as you 'now' (ie when they ask) know they already knew.

Comment: And what if you found out they knew only after the question they asked? and normally "now" you think they don' know.

Comment: You only _do_ know they know after they have asked. Surely that's the point of the question. The future situation would be handled by 'How are you going to respond to the counter-intelligence agencies when they ask you about the things you thought they had no idea about?' I'd still want 'had' here. ' ... about the things you think they have no idea about?' also works, but has a different emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Edwin, **had** is your best bet.  I'm going to try to explain why in a simple way.

We don't want the listener to get confused, going back and forth between present and past.  Since we have to say *you **thought***, it works best to stick with the past tense, and say *they **had** no idea about*.